# Exercise 5, book Differential equations, Stephen Smale

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The exercise is on the page 241. Says:

Let $X\subset \Omega$ be a nonempty compact invariant set for a $C^1$ dynamical system $\phi:\mathbb{R}\times \Omega\rightarrow \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Suppose that $X$ is minimal, that is, $X$ contains no compact invariant nonempty proper subset. Prove the following:

1. Every trajectory in $X$ is dense in $X$;
2. $L_\alpha(x)=L_\omega(x)=X$ for each $x\in X$ ( here $L_\omega(x)=\{a:\exists t_n\rightarrow \infty\text{ with }\phi_{t_n}(x)\rightarrow \infty\}$, $L_\alpha(x)$ similar with $t_n\rightarrow-\infty$);
3. For any (relatively) open set $U\subset X$, there is a number $P>0$ such that for any $x\in X$, $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi_t(x)\in U$ and $|t-t_0|<P$;
4. For any $x$, $y$ in $X$ there are sequences $t_n\rightarrow\infty$, $s_n\rightarrow\infty$ such that
   $$|t_n-t_{n+1}|<2P,|s_n-s_{n+1}|<2P,$$
   and
   $$\phi_{t_n}(x)\rightarrow y,\phi_{s_n}(x)\rightarrow y$$

I already proved 1 and 2. For 3, my idea is given $x\in X$ and $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$, since the set
$$A=\{\phi_t(x):t\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
is dense in X then exists $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi_t(x)\in U$.

Then, take $M_x=|t-t_0|$ and consider the set of all such $M_x$. If I prove that $M=\sup\{M_x\}< \infty$ then for any $x\in X$ exists $t$ such that $\phi_t(x)\in U$ and
$$|t-t_0|\leq M < M+1=P$$
Question 1: How I can prove $M$ is finite? or am I on the wrong track?

Question 2: How I can prove 4? (Which I am lost)

Comment: In 2. you mean $x(t_n)\to a$ for $n\to \infty$? In 3., there is no condition saying what $t$ is and how it connects to $U$. The $P$ in 3. is connected to the subset $U$. What is $P$ in 4.? Generally, is "dynamical system" an autonomous ODE, and $\phi$ its flow function?

Comment: Thanks for the observations. First question, yes. Second questions $\phi_t(x)\in U$ (I missed to write it, but I already did). Third questions, I guess it is the positive number $P$ found in 3. Fourth question, yes (I rewrite it so it is clearer).